# User Interface SDK for HiSilicon processor

Tags: c++, c, linux, user-interface, embedded

We are developing a software on Hi3536 processor based board. The `SDK` provided by `HiSilicon` comes with samples for developing user interface using frame buffer API - which is too low level. i.e., to design Combo Box, Text box, we have to write code from Scratch.

We are now trying to use QT. Not sure what other vendors do use for developing software on Hi3535 or Hi3536.

Can somebody suggest which `SDK` is most suitable for developing user Interface on `HiSilicon` processor based boards ?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We referred the sample code given in the following link and we would bring up the GUI successfully in Hi3536 using QT 5.6 - http://bbs.ebaina.com/thread-8217-1-1.html.

Please note that you need to use Google translator to translate the text in chinese.

Answer (score -1):

In a past job, a few years ago, I worked on a GUI for an older Hisilicon chip based board.
I greatly enjoyed using [Qt for Embedded Linux](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-embedded-linux.html), version 4.8 on Linux framebuffer.
As far as I remember, be sure to study the Hisilicon documentation on how the framebuffers can/must be initialized and used. Hisilicon SDK used to contain also some sample programs with source code, there should be one that deals with framebuffers too.
My knowledge of Qt for Embedded is stuck at 4.8, I know version 5.x has radically re-designed that part, but I can't help you on details related to Qt5.

Comment: Mainly, Qt5 needs a GPU to work. If SoC has it, you could move to Qt5 easely getting rid of QWS

Comment: Many Thanks roalz and LPs. We would like to use GPU for some other task. Looks like devices like NVRs running on HiSilicon processors are using some home grown SDK or some third party SDKs - Just a guess, by looking at the GUI. Hence, I am looking for alternative to QT, which may be smaller in size.

Comment: The product I worked on is exactly an NVR on-board GUI interface (the NVR is still sold today as the primary NVR product line by an international company), if I would have done it today, I would have still considered Qt anyway, the development speed you'll get is impressive IMHO.

Comment: Thank you roalz. It is indeed faster with QT.

Comment: To whoever downvoted my answer: please explain me why.

Comment: @Venkata it would be appreciated if you upvote and/or accept my answer, if it i useful for you.

Comment: We went ahead with QT as it is easier to develop GUI

Comment: Here is a link which has the code for QT as well - http://bbs.ebaina.com/thread-8217-1-1.html. We used this as reference and successfully brought up the GUI in Hi3536 using QT 5.6